# Objective-C, iPhone How play audio files from different URLs in sequence?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, audio, nsurlconnection

I need to play 3 audio files in sequence, from 3 different URLs in my iPhone app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AVQueuePlayer` does exactly this.  Create an array of `AVPlayerItem` objects, and pass in the array when you create the `AVQueuePlayer`.

- [AVQueuePlayer Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010168)

Comment: Dear gavinb, Thanks! I'm not using the AVPlayer class, but my custom player for WMA files. Even so, can I still implement the AVQueuePlayer somehow?

Comment: Dear gavinb, Thanks! I'm not using the AVPlayer class, but my custom player for WMA files, inheriting straight from NSObject. Even so, can I still implement the AVQueuePlayer somehow?

Comment: Ah, so it would have been really useful to mention the fact that you're using a custom player in your question! In that case, presumably the player is running in its own thread?  So you would use a notification or callback to signal the main control thread that the current file is finished so it can schedule the next. It's hard to advise more without knowing details of your custom player.

Comment: You guessed right, it's a multi thread player. I'll try to think of some sort of signaling the main thread and if I need any other specific advice I'll leave you a note here. THANKS a lot for your attention and willingness to help me!!!

Comment: @Winston You're most welcome. Have a look at using NSNotification for sending a message from your player to your controller.  You could also define a protocol and use a delegate pattern.  Have fun. :)

Comment: I've used NSNotification and now I'm able to play all URLs in sequence! Thanks gavinb!